# Clear data of one child component when another another child component button is clicked

Tags: angular

I have created a component for autocomplete-text-view which I have to use in many pages.

In the parent class, I have used that child component 3 times, which means the page has 3 autocomplete-text-view.

Each `autocomplete-text-view` component has a clear button.

Now If I click the clear button of the first `autocomplete-text-view` the data of other 2 `autocomplete-text-view` s input field should get cleared.

Please help me how can achieve this.

```
I have used `@Output` decorator and emitted the event to parent component .So that I can pass empty message using `@Input` decorator to clear the data of other 2 `autocomplete-text-view` .But it is not working.
```

*parentcomponent.html*

```
<app-search-bar   (clear)="subchapter_select=''"></app-search-bar>

<app-search-bar  [search_key]="subchapter_select"  (clear)="op=''">
</app-search-bar>

<app-search-bar [search_key]="op"  ">
</app-search-bar>
```

*childcomponent.ts*

```
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() search_key;
 @Output() clear = new EventEmitter();


  clearText(){
   this.clear.emit();//emiting event from child component to parent
  }
}
```

When I click on the clear button of first `autocomplete-text-view` .The data on the input field of other `autocomplete-text-view`  should get clear

Comment: You're probably going to want to use a shared service for component communication. Here is a stackblitz as an example, hope it helps. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgwsrv

Comment: Thank you.I need the output like When i click on the first item clear button it has to clear other 2.If i click on clear button of 2nd item it has to clear the 3rd one. Please check this link  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h1adnp.Now with your help i could clear 2 and 3 item ,when i click on 1st item.Now I want clear only 3rd item when i click on second item